# Google Maps Javascript API not working for search Box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

[image]
This is the error I'm getting while accessing search box javascript API. I get a console error API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError. But when I check it in my console, I find that Javascript API is enabled. It works fine for normal maps display.  Not sure why is the error. ANy help would be appreciated.

Code:

```js
<script>
    "use strict";

    // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
    // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
    // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.
    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">
    function initAutocomplete() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: {
                lat: -33.8688,
                lng: 151.2195
            },
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: "roadmap"
        }); // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

        const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
        const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input); // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.

        map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });
        let markers = []; // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.

        searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
            const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            } // Clear out the old markers.

            markers.forEach(marker => {
                marker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = []; // For each place, get the icon, name and location.

            const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(place => {
                if (!place.geometry) {
                    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                    return;
                }

                const icon = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                }; // Create a marker for each place.

                markers.push(
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        map,
                        icon,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    })
                );

                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    // Only geocodes have viewport.
                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In order to use services like places library or geocoding you have to enable in addition to Google Maps JavaScript API corresponding web service. In your case I believe you should enable Places API, because you use places library in your code.

Comment: Thanks @xomena I'll give a try enabling Places API